# Samsung Galaxy Ace doesn't see sdcard

Tags: external-sd, samsung-galaxy-ace

My Galaxy Ace was working fine until this morning. it's now failing to read any sdcard. I have tried factory reset but still it doesn't recognize the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the card to a laptop or a PC via a card reader and see if the card is working correctly.Also format the card from the mobile and see if that works.